# Chaining queries/transactions in Knex?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, knex.js

I would like to chain queries without nesting callbacks. I would like something akin to:

```
knex.select('column')
    .from('table')
    .then(handleData)
    .thenPrepareForNextQuery()
    .select('otherColumn')
    .....
```

I think the closest thing to describe this would be reactive or monadic programming.

Answer (score 3):

```
myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve,error){ resolve('param!') });
myPromise
  .then(function(x){
    console.log(x);
    return knex.select('column')
               .from('table')
               .then(handleData);
  })
  .then(function(data_from_handleData){
    return knex.select('another_column')
               .from('another_table')
  })
```

Comment: Or you can also forgo the `myPromise = new Promise...` and just start with a `knex.select(...)` to construct a `Promise`.